# console.log($(this).....()[0].innerHTML - sometimes prints the right Value sometimes it prints all of the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting crazy over this..right when I thought I made it somehow it shows me "nope not this time..."

So what my code is supposed to do is , in a table for each row in specific column create dropdown lists, based on a value from another column.-i.e. my dropdown lists are not same in each row.

Why is there a problem...because that other Column from where I have to check the value is also a DDL but with already selected value. (**Cascading DDLs**) and **NO** I don't need the **on.('change', function)** since I alredy did this. 
my problem is when a user alredy selected from both DDLs and does the UPDATE table, I want him to still be able to change the selected options , meaning both DDL should alredy be there. it works for the FIRST DDL since I just check the *:selected* value and rest are added normally. But I have the problem with the second one. When doing this:

```
console.log($tr.find("td:eq(16)").parents("tr").children("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML;)
```

..to find the value of the FIRST DDL it either returns me the right value or it shows me all select options and then is my code not able to work the rest of the magic -.-

This is my code currently: (first part is the code with "on.change" second is the one with the problem..but I added whole code so you can see the ajax call also)

```
//create dropdown for Type -they are dependent on the CI Values - also have ID_Number that will be saved for later use
var CI_JSON_File = [];
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"{{url_for('CIType')}}",
    success:function(data){
        //parse JSON data in order to show it as JSON and not a String
        // then group it in order to gain access to each Subtype for each CI
        result = JSON.parse(data).reduce((acc,elm)=>{
        if ( acc[elm.CI] ) acc[elm.CI].push( { Type:elm.Type, TypeValue:elm.TypeValue } )
        else acc[elm.CI] = [{ Type:elm.Type, TypeValue:elm.TypeValue }]
        return acc
        },{})
        $.each(result, function(index, val){
            //get each array inside the JSON file, to gain access to CI Types 
            CI_JSON_File[index] = val;
        });,
        //code used to add DDL based on change in CI DDL
        $('#my_id').on('change', '#CISelect', function(event){
            var CIValue = $(this).val();
            var TypeSelect = ""; 
            var htmlOption = '<option value="0"> Select Type</option>';
            if(CIValue !== '0'){
                var typeCI = CI_JSON_File[CIValue];
                $.each(typeCI, function(key, value){
                    htmlOption += '<option value="' + value.TypeValue + '">' + value.Type + '</option>'; 
                });
            }
            TypeSelect = "<select value='CIType'>" + htmlOption + '</select>';
            $(this).parents('tr').children('td:eq(16)').empty().append(TypeSelect);
        });

        //this code is used to check if there is already a value in the selected box and if so to select it in the 
        //dropdown list, and show the Type and not only the TypeValue
        $(function(){

        console.log("ready");
        $('#my_id tr').each(function(){
            var optionType = "";
            var selectType = "";
            const $tr = $(this);
            var selectedType = $tr.find("td:eq(16)")[0];
            console.log(selectedType);
            if(selectedType){
                //get the CI value that vas selected before
                console.log(selectedType.innerHTML);
                var CIBefore =  $tr.find("td:eq(16)").parents("tr").children("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML;
                console.log(CIBefore);
                var typeCIBefore = CI_JSON_File[CIBefore];
                console.log(typeCIBefore);
                var typeCIBefore = CI_JSON_File[CIBefore];
                $.each(typeCIBefore, function(key, value){
                    if(selectedType === value.TypeValue){
                       optionType += '<option selected="selected" value="' + value.TypeValue + '">' + value.Type + '</option>';
                    }
                    else{
                        optionType += '<option value="' + value.TypeValue + '">' + value.Type + '</option>';
                    }
                });
                selectType = '<select class = "CITypeSelect">' + optionType + '</select>';
                $tr.find('td:eq(16)').empty().append(selectType);


            }
            //selectType =  "<select value='CIType'>" + optionType + '</select>';
            //$(this).parents('tr').children('td:eq(16)').empty().append(selectType);
        });
    })


    }
});
```

The tables for th DDL are from ajax called JSON file. But somehow I can't get the right values.

I really have no idea what am I doing wrong anymore :( and I am still learning about the JS jquery.. so any help would be great.

Comment: Instead of `parents("tr")` you should probably use `closest("tr")` or instead of `.parents("tr").children("td:eq(15)")` you could use `prev()` (for 16th TD the previous element should be 15th TD). Instead of `[0].innerHTML` you can use method `html()` or better to get value selected in DDL you can use `.find('select').val()`.

Comment: I tried all of that and it still changed each time :/ .. it returns me **undefined**

Comment: I suggest you to use the .siblings(), next() or prev() jquery selectors, instead selecting child then parent then child and so

Comment: You should not use `console.log` to check a variable (https://hackernoon.com/please-stop-using-console-log-its-broken-b5d7d396cf15). Just to make sure, you may want to change your `console.log($tr.find("td:eq(16)").parents("tr").children("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML;)` to  `var d = $tr.find("td:eq(16)").parents("tr").children("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML; debugger;` and then examine the value in `d`.

Comment: @vqf thanks for info, I corrected my code..changed all of the **parents.childen...** code to **prev...next** and it still sometimes shows me undefined ... does it maybe have to do with values are int and not strings ? I am really going crazy over this

Comment: It was just a suggestion, because these problems might give you a "now it works, now it doesn't" kind of headache. If you need more help, I would advice you to create a working minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that one can debug the code. You can also use jfiddle or codepen.